# What is the significance of the name Bastian Balthazar Bux?

Tags: name-significance, german-language, michael-ende, the-neverending-story

Apart from being triply alliterative (BBB), what is the significance of the name **Bastian Balathazar Bux** (or **Bastian Balthasar Bux** in the German original), the protagonist of *The Neverending Story*? [Balthasar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balthazar_(magus)) was one of the biblical Magi (Three Wise Men), Bastian reminds me of [bastion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bastion) which is apparently [the same word in German](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bastion), and I've no idea about Bux. Surely, in a story as carefully crafted and multiply layered as this one, the main character's name will be carefully chosen to have some special significance.

Comment: See also https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/6103/139 which asks about the initials.

Comment: Bastian is also a shorter form of Sebastian.